# how to verify that the following statement is true/false

Tags: general-topology

Let $D$ = {$(x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2  : x^2 + y^2 < 1$}.verify that the following statement is true/false.

Given a continuous function $g : D →\mathbb{R}$, there always exists a continuous function $f : \mathbb{R}^2 → \mathbb{R}$ such that $f = g$ on $D$

how can I able to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Consider the function $g: [0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x) = \sin \frac {1}{x-1}$. It cannot be extended to $[0,1]$ in a continuous manner.

Comment: That's true, in order to be an answer. I made it a hint instead.

Comment: I just noticed that; sorry for the false

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Tietze Extension Theorem. It does not apply here but it can tell you some interesting stuff.